# Nginx перенаправить запрос в php, если файла не существует

Tags: php, сервер, nginx, веб-сервер

Изучаю nginx, интересно реализовать такую схему: если запрошенный файл (кроме index.php) есть в папке - отдать его, иначе открыть index.php

Подскажите правило для location

Так я мог бы эффективно отдавать статический контент вроде картинок, музыки и видео, js, css и прочего (например txt файлов и т.д.)

Конечно, можно вообще все запросы перенаправлять в index.php и там уже проверять существование файла, но во первых зачем мне писать дополнительный лишний код, а что более важно, это совсем не так эффективно как nginx, созданный для того, что бы быть почти идеальным, когда речь о статике.

p.s. Я знаю что для медиа файлов нужен отдельный адресс, а ещё лучше CDN, но вопрос не об этом

**UPD**

Составил пример того, что мне нужно. Проблема этого примера в том, что содержимое блока дважды повторяется.

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.loc;
    root /var/www/site.loc;

    location ~* ^/(index.php)?$ {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }

    location ~* /.* {
        try_files 
            $uri $uri/ @php_control;
    }

    location @php_control {
        include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
        fastcgi_param  SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2):

Первый `location` можно сделать точным, второй префиксным, а директивы `include` и `fastcgi_param` вынести на уровень выше:

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.loc;
    root /var/www/site.loc;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;

    location = /index.php {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php_control;
    }

    location @php_control {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

---

Пример с внутренним перенаправлением чтобы два раза не писать `fastcgi_pass` (но это не очень читаемо):

```
server {
    listen 80;
    server_name site.loc;
    root /var/www/site.loc;
    include /etc/nginx/fastcgi_params;
    fastcgi_param SCRIPT_FILENAME $document_root/index.php;
    error_page 418 = @php_control;

    location = /index.php {
        return 418; # Специальный код для заварки кофе.
    }

    location / {
        try_files $uri $uri/ @php_control;
    }

    location @php_control {
        fastcgi_pass unix:/var/run/php-fpm/php-fpm.sock;
    }
}
```

Comment: Это неправильный пример. Знаете что будет, если я запрошу /img.jpg?

Comment: @TryCatch Что будет? Должно работать.

Comment: Скажет что файл не найден. Потому что нет правила `location ~* /.*`, но ок, принцип я понял. Если это единственный вариант - жаль, потому что это все равно повторение, я думал есть вариант прямого перенаправления в другой (именованный) location

Comment: @TryCatch Нет, `/img.jpg` даст совпадение с `location /`, префикс же с начальной частью uri должен совпасть, т.е. `location /` идентичен `location ~* /.*`, но запись проще и теоретически без регулярки будет работать быстрее. Чтобы не повторяться можно использовать внутреннее перенаправление при помощи директив `error_page` и `return`, но это увеличит конфиг на одну строку и по-моему сделает код менее читаемым.

Comment: Я думал что `error_page ` перенаправляет пользователя на другую страницу. Это работает не так? То есть если я просто напишу `return @php_control;` - то исполнится @php_control? Если да, то это именно то, что мне нужно

Comment: @TryCatch В `return` нельзя использовать именованный `location`, а `error_page` работает по другому. Дополнил ответ.

Comment: Это просто ужасно выглядит. Странно что в nginx нельзя просто сказать "перейди пожалуйста к такому-то location"